# Ruby, limit the number of files returned with Find module per request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I have a controller that calls a find_photos method, passing it a query string (name of file)

```
class BrandingPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.find_photos(query)
    require "find"

    found_photos = []

    Find.find("u_photos/photo_browse/photos/") do |img_path|
        # break off just the filename from full path
        img = img_path.split('/').last

        if query.blank? || query.empty?
        # if query is blank, they submitted the form with browse all- return all photos
            found_photos << img
        else
        # otherwise see if the file includes their query and return it
            found_photos << img if img.include?(query)
        end
    end

    found_photos.empty? ? "no results found" : found_photos
  end
end
```

This is just searching a directory full of photos- there is no table backing this.

Ideally what I would like is to be able to limit the number of results returned by find_photos to around 10-15, then fetch the next 10-15 results as needed.

I was thinking that the code to do this might involve looping through 10 times and grabbing those files- store the last filename in a variable or as a parameter, and then send that variable back to the method, telling it to continue the search from that filename.

This assumes that the files are looped through in the same order everytime, and that there is no simpler way to accomplish this.

If there are any suggestions, I'd love to hear them/see some examples of how you'd accomplish this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you write some tests/specs for the behaviour you're looking for? How would you want to call this method? How would you continue from where you left off? It helps to design the API in specs and then work your way from there. Also take a look at Ruby's [Enumarable](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable) API for what you can already achieve with Ruby itself. I looks like you can slim down the code to a single line with the methods from Enumerable.

Comment: I can't think of a simple way to do this.  You might want to wrap the find in your own class that memoizes the directory listing and implements pagination.  You could have it memoize for a certain amount of time, or implement a way to register new images.  You'd probably be better off storing image metadata in a database if you need to do this sort of thing.  You might want to check out the [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) and [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gems for image management.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind for this problem is to cut the array down after you come out of the loop.  This wouldn't work well with a ton of files though  A different solution might be to add a break for the size of the array viz. `break if found_photos.length > 10` inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard to do what you want, but you need to consider how you'll handle entries that are added or removed in-between page loads, filenames with UTF-8 or Unicode characters, and embedded/parent directories.

This is old-school code for the basis for what you're talking about:

```
require 'erb'
require 'sinatra'

get '/list_photos' do

  dir    = params[ :dir    ]
  offset = params[ :offset ].to_i
  num    = params[ :num    ].to_i

  files = Dir.entries(dir).reject{ |fn| fn[/^\./] || File.directory?(File.join(dir, fn)) }
  total_files = files.size

  prev_a = next_a = ''

  if (offset > 0)
    prev_a = "<a href='/list_photos?dir=#{ dir }&num=#{ num }&offset=#{ [ 0, offset - num ].max }'>&lt;&lt; Previous</a>"
  end

  if (offset < total_files)
    next_a = "<a href='/list_photos?dir=#{ dir }&num=#{ num }&offset=#{ [ total_files, offset + num ].min }'>Next &gt;&gt;</a>"
  end

  files_to_display = files[offset, num]

  template = ERB.new <<EOF
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
    <% files_to_display.each do |f| %>
      <tr><td><%= f %></td></tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
    <%= prev_a %> | <%= total_files %> files | <%= next_a %>
  </body>
</html>
EOF

  content_type 'text/html'
  template.result(binding)

end
```

It's a little Sinatra server, so save it as `test.rb` and run from the command-line using:

```
ruby test.rb
```

In a browser connect to the running Sinatra server using a URL like:

```
http://hostname:4567/list_photos?dir=/path/to/image/files&num=10&offset=0
```

I'm using Sinatra for convenience, but the guts of the routine is the basis for what you want. How to convert it into Rails terms is left as an exercise for the reader.